# Single-page application: Sign-in and Sign-out

Tags: reactjs, azure, micro-frontend

have any of you used Azure authentication? Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=react, I have a problem logging out. Logging in takes place in the Account microtext and the logout button is in the header, which is a separate frontend. When I want to log out I use this code:

```
let myStorage = window.localStorage;
  let homeAccountId = myStorage.homeAccountId;

  async function logout(e) {
    const currentAccount = instance.getAccountByHomeId(homeAccountId);
    await instance.logoutRedirect({
      account: currentAccount,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "/account",
    });
  }
```

and I get an error: AuthError.js: 27 Uncaught (in promise) BrowserConfigurationAuthError: stubbed_public_client_application_called: Stub instance of Public Client Application was called. If using msal-react, please ensure context is not used without a provider. For more visit: aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors

Comment: Could you please add more info to answer more precisely , meanwhile you can refer this link for build single page app in react using azure AD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/react?tutorial-step=1 and https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/errors.md